# Activity keeps restarting when orientation changes

Tags: java, android, android-activity

how do you keep the activity from restarting when the screen rotates or when then user slides the keyboard on the phone? Is this possible? Is there a work around or something? All relevant answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by declaring a specific attribute in your `activity` element in your `manifest.xml`.  The element in question is called `android:configChanges`, and you need to register the string value of `orientation`.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html):

> Now when one of these configurations change, MyActivity is not
>   restarted. Instead, the Activity receives a call to
>   onConfigurationChanged(). This method is passed a Configuration object
>   that specifies the new device configuration. By reading fields in the
>   Configuration, you can determine the new configuration and make
>   appropriate changes by updating the resources used in your interface.
>   At the time this method is called, your Activity's Resources object is
>   updated to return resources based on the new configuration, so you can
>   easily reset elements of your UI without the system restarting your
>   Activity

So doing this will cause your `Activity` to not restart, and will also callback to `onConfigurationChanged()` so that ***you*** can handle the change yourself.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code? I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: What is it that you cannot seem to get to work?  Could you provide an update to your question by editing it?  It would be helpful if you would mention what you have tried, and what specifically isn't working.

Comment: In addition of "orientation", per your question you might also want to add related keyboard config changes to handle keyboard action, so the value that you might want to put is "orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden". As Nicholas said, you probably want/need to handle onConfigurationChanged() yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges), you will see that you can specify the following in your manifest:

```xml
<activity ...
    android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Once you have this you can implement the [`onConfigurationChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method to receive notifications about orientation change, or just use the base class's implementation.

Comment: @Arvin The two answers are 4 minutes apart. It's unlikely that this answer was a "copy", just an equivalent answer that was posted concurrently. It happens all the time and isn't a big deal. People generally upvote the earlier answer more unless the later answer actually adds something useful. Your comment sounds like sour grapes for having your own answer downvoted.