# Can I call startActivity() from within onResume()?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android activity that needs to call another activity (to get a password from the user) before its own screen is brought up. My code currently does this by calling startActivity() from within onResume(); it sort of works, but I have been getting inconsistent behaviour. Can anyone tell me whether this approach is legal or not (and if not, how should I do it) ?

Thanks, Richard.

Comment: Define _inconsistent_ behaviour?

Comment: The oddities occur when the activity gets destroyed and re-created on change of screen orientation. Going from portrait to landscape produces a different sequence of calls to the two activities' methods (stop, resume et al) than the other way around, and the sequence is different again under the debugger; I suspect some sort of race condition. I've also just noticed that logcat has complaints of 'unexpected resume while resumed' from system_process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `startActivity()` in `onResume()` is absolutely fine. I have many activities which do this, often in reaction to events which have happened while the activity was stopped.

All `startActivity()` does is tell Android to start the new activity and add it to the top of the back stack when the main thread becomes available, which in this instance will be after Android has finished calling all the necessary lifecycle callbacks on the current activity.

If you are experiencing odd behaviour I doubt is related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call startActivity() from onResume() but it is an async call. So onResume() (and the current activity's other methods) will keep running until the Android OS gets around to your startActivity() async call and starts the new activity.

The *inconsistent* behaviour you are experiencing is probably related to you activity continuing for an indefinite period of time until the OS loads the new activity.

Comment: `startActivity()` is asynchronous, but that means that it is non-blocking, not that it is blocking, and `onResume()` continues immediately after the call, it does not wait for the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is legal, but depending on what you want to do exactly it might be impractical. A common way is to start with your "second" activity as would be defined in the manifest and then hand over to the first activity. Yet another way would be to start an activity for result in e.g. `onCreate()`, which can be done even before calling any `setContentView()`. There are many many ways of doing this, so I guess we need a little more info to be able to provide a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like a good idea.

Some alternatives:

- To ask for the password, you could use a Dialog instead of an Activity.
- why not always go via this intermediate activity. In case there is no need to prompt for a password it could show something else, like an animation while you connect to the service (assuming the password is a network thing)

Comment: The password decrypts the content shown by the activity, so I would prefer to have the password available _before_ I display the data. I don't have any choice about activity order, because this issue occurs when the screen orientation changes (I deliberately delete the password when the activity is destroyed).

Comment: Do users accept having to re-enter their password whenever they turn the device?

Comment: Well, in this case, I _am_ the user. But  yes, I do need to find a way to stop that happening on change of screen orientation.

Comment: There are ways to prevent the activity from restarting. cfr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129404/activity-keeps-restarting-when-orientation-changes